# Is there a quick way to unbind keys in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I did a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> to view all my bindings in emacs. Now I want to unbind a **lot** of keys, simply because I never use those functions of Emacs and I don't want to perform them when I accidently press the bound keys! This also frees up a lot of keys for other tasks (for use with Cedet for example). So apart from global-unset-key, is there any method to remove bindings in bulk?

`C-a     move-beginning-of-line
C-b     backward-char
C-c     mode-specific-command-prefix
C-d     delete-char
C-e     move-end-of-line
C-f     forward-char
C-g     keyboard-quit
C-h     help-command
C-k     kill-line
C-l     recenter-top-bottom
C-n     next-line
C-o     open-line
C-p     previous-line
C-q     quoted-insert
C-t     transpose-chars
C-u     universal-argument
C-v     scroll-up
C-x     Control-X-prefix
C-z     suspend-frame
ESC     ESC-prefix`

I want to remove most of these bindings which are absolutely useless for me.

Comment: If you want to use the "standard" keybindings of `C-v` for `yank`, `C-x` for `kill-region` and so on, check out `cua-mode`, which achieves this while preserving Emacs's functionality.

Comment: Bear in mind these are really a **lot** of bindings, especially with emacs [Named-ASCII-Chars](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Named-ASCII-Chars.html#Named-ASCII-Chars). **Disabling `ESC` (`"\e"`) disables almost everything based on the meta key** (in here at least). Also `C-c` and `C-x` are first-class prefixes branching to many commands.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's no built-in way to unset a lot of keys, because it's easy to do it yourself:

(Edited for strict correctness:)

```
(dolist (key '("\C-a" "\C-b" "\C-c" "\C-d" "\C-e" "\C-f" "\C-g"
               "\C-h" "\C-k" "\C-l" "\C-n" "\C-o" "\C-p" "\C-q"
               "\C-t" "\C-u" "\C-v" "\C-x" "\C-z" "\e"))
  (global-unset-key key))
```

Although I have to say that most of the commands you call "useless" I would call "essential."

(Edited to add:)

As for freeing up keys for other tasks, there's plenty of unused key real estate:

- Key sequences consisting of `C-c` followed by a letter are by convention reserved for users.
- If you have an extra modifier available, like Option on the Mac or the Windows key on a PC, you can associate it with an Emacs modifier like `super`.  I have `super-b` bound to `browse-url-at-point`, for example.
- If you're not on a plain terminal, the shift key becomes available to distinguish key sequences.  For example, I have `shift-meta-b` bound to `bury-buffer`.
- For commands that are useful but not run often enough to warrant a dedicated key sequence, you can use `defalias` to provide a shorter name.  In my .emacs file, I have `(defalias 'ru 'rename-uniquely)` and `(defalias 'c 'calendar)` (among many others).

Comment: yes, but I use `home` `end` and arrow keys etc to achieve the same effect. I am so used to these that I find it too difficult to adapt to some other navigation keys. Plus I would like keys like these to be available to me for doing tasks that are more important to me. For example I'd like to undo using a C-z because I find it very difficult to do multiple undo using the default `C-x C-u` thing.

Comment: This has worked for all keys except C-z which is somehow minimizing emacs though it is supposed to be "suspending buffer". Is there anything I am missing here ?

Comment: Hey it worked once and the next time it stopped working .. could you help me debug it ? I copy pasted the exact same thing both times and now I can't get it to work .. It keeps saying "-Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p key)" !! :( :(

Comment: Rather than unbinding them, I'd just get used to C-a and C-e in particular. You'll eventually save a lot of time over taking your hands off the home row.

Comment: @drys but these don't work with any other editor .. If I get used to these I am going to have a lot of trouble working with other  editors !

Comment: That's why I'm gradually folding all my other editors into emacs. Even my browser is now "conkeror", which basically reimplements (a tiny fraction of) emacs in a browser.

Comment: @Sean, `kbd` is meant for constant strings not variables.  Use `read-kbd-macro`.

Comment: @event_jr: Thanks for the tip.  I rarely use `kbd` myself, only used it here in an attempt to simplify, and wasn't about to test the code in my long-running Emacs session.

Comment: I'm glad this answer actually helps the OP *before* stating any variant of “you should learn these keys” (with which I agree, but which has nothing to do with the question asked). +1 for many reasons :·)

Answer (score 13):

`global-unset-key` and `local-unset-key` are useful, but it's worth having an answer to this question that points out that the *general* way to unbind a key (for *any* keymap) is to define a binding of `nil`:

```el
(define-key KEYMAP KEY nil)
```

If you follow the code for either of those other functions, you'll notice that this is exactly what they do.

Comment: In emacs 24, setting a default key to nil has no effect, and preserves the default.

Comment: What do you mean by "a default key"?

Comment: A key that comes with emacs defaults, without adding a .emacs or changing the init file. For example, "M-)" defaults for `move-past-close-and-reindent`.

Comment: That binding is in the global keymap, and so *either* of the following work just fine, as stated: `(define-key global-map (kbd "M-)") nil)` or `(global-unset-key (kbd "M-)"))`. If this approach doesn't appear to work, you're simply using the wrong keymap (or the binding appears in multiple keymaps, and you need to do it for more than one).

Comment: I know what you say. I use this keybinding all the time. It disturbs me only in python-mode,, and I tried to purge it only there. I want to keep the global binding.

Comment: I think you're confused about how keymaps and bindings work. If `M-)` is not defined in python-mode's keymap, then you cannot unbind it from *that* keymap, because there's nothing to unbind. You could, OTOH, *bind* it for that keymap in order to take precedence over the global binding. I recommend that you read Mickey's excellent article about Emacs keybindings: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/

Comment: Man, I know keymaps and emacs. I programmed major modes (google for example for Backus-Naur major mode that was written by me ). My current solution was to local bind in python-mode-map a dummy lambda-interactive function so: ``(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "M-)") (lambda () (interactive)))``, in order to overwrite the bad function . I need more intelligent solution. I need to remove that binding only in python-mode. Yes, I did not think too much to this problem, but into a hurry I tried to purge it, because it disturbs me -- I use these days python mode > 10 hours per day.

Comment: What you've done is fine. Even better, write a python-mode function which does something vaguely analogous to the original function. Otherwise there are various approaches you could take involving making global-map buffer-local in python mode, but personally I wouldn't recommend doing it.